# The name "Expander" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I have installed the **Microsoft.Toolkit version 2.2.0** and my **Visual Studio** *version* is **15.6.6**.

Here I got this error when trying the **Expander Control** in **UWP**

```
The name "Expander" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
```

Answer (score 1):

The UWP Toolkit is broken up into a few NuGet packages.  Is **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls** listed in your References?  If not add it via NuGet.